# How can I get a text with no tag in xml file by python

Tags: python, regex, xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<GateDocument>
<!-- The document content area with serialized nodes -->

<TextWithNodes><Node id="0" />Norway<Node id="6" /> <Node id="7" 
/>to<Node id="9" /> <Node id="10" />'<Node id="11" />completely<Node 
id="21" /> <Node id="22" />ban<Node id="25" /> <Node id="26" 
/>petrol<Node id="32" /> <Node id="33" />powered<Node id="40" /> <Node 
id="41" />cars<Node id="45" /> <Node id="46" />by<Node id="48" /> <Node 
id="49" />2025<Node id="53" />'<Node id="54" />.<Node id="55" /> . 
</TextWithNodes>
</GateDocument>
```

From the above XML file, you can notice that the words in "TextWithNodes" tag have no tags. How could I get for example "petrol powered cars" text by python

Thank you

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: Another alternative without using intertext, is doing a harder pattern.

__(?!\>)[^<>"\s]+(?=\<)__

https://regex101.com/r/7ZByy7/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `itertext()` method after you find the node you want with `findall()`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
x = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<GateDocument>
<!-- The document content area with serialized nodes -->

<TextWithNodes><Node id="0" />Norway<Node id="6" /> <Node id="7"
/>to<Node id="9" /> <Node id="10" />'<Node id="11" />completely<Node
id="21" /> <Node id="22" />ban<Node id="25" /> <Node id="26"
/>petrol<Node id="32" /> <Node id="33" />powered<Node id="40" /> <Node
id="41" />cars<Node id="45" /> <Node id="46" />by<Node id="48" /> <Node
id="49" />2025<Node id="53" />'<Node id="54" />.<Node id="55" /> .
</TextWithNodes>
</GateDocument>'''
t = ET.fromstring(x)
print(''.join(t.findall('.//TextWithNodes')[0].itertext()))
```

This outputs:

```
Norway to 'completely ban petrol powered cars by 2025'. .
```